# Changing existing regex so at least 1 numerical value is required

Tags: regex

Said regex: `\b(?=(?:[a-z\d]*[A-Z]){3})(?=.*\d)(?=(?:[A-Z\d]*[a-z]){2})[a-zA-Z\d]{5,30}\b`

I am trying to add just 1 condition to this regex, that being that 1 number is required in order to match, I have tried inserting the lookahead (?=.*\d) but it did not work, as it matches the "HeLLoWoRlD" portion of <HeLLoWoRlD"123

Comment: String literal as in something like “hello, world”? If so, no.

Comment: It appears you just want to limit the digit check within a word, replace `(?=.*\d)` with `(?=[A-Za-z]*\d)`

Comment: If I wasn't being specific in my question, I am basically asking to modify \b(?=(?:[a-z\d]*[A-Z]){3})(?=(?:[A-Z\d]*[a-z]){2})[a-zA-Z\d]{5,30}\b so it fits all these requirements https://regex101.com/r/w9BMgW/8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may add the `(?=[A-Za-z]*\d)` lookahead check:

```
\b(?=[A-Za-z]*\d)(?=(?:[a-z\d]*[A-Z]){3})(?=(?:[A-Z\d]*[a-z]){2})[a-zA-Z\d]{5,30}\b
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/w9BMgW/9).

The `(?=[A-Za-z]*\d)` lookahead matches a location that is immediately followed with 0 or more ASCII letters and then one digit.